# Error printing an associative array (error:unexpected "", expecting T_STRING or T_NUM STRING)

Tags: php, syntax-error, associative-array

I have the code:

```
print <<<HERE
<p>$myInfo["lastName"]</p>
HERE;
```

and get the error:

> error:unexpected "", expecting T_STRING or T_NUM STRING

What is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variable interpolation syntax is either

```
"$var[key]"
```

*or*

```
"{$var['key']}"
```

Note the curly braces you need to use the *complex syntax*.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing